# how can I get an unique index for each instance of one Class in Android?

Tags: android, mysql

If I insert the data of every instance into the database, every instance can obtain the unique ID(primary key auto increment in database). But I can`t know what the ID of this instance is before the data insert into database.

Or I can traverse the database to get the current max index and use max index+1 to identify the new instance , but this way I think is too inefficient.

Please tell me the way you usually do to get ID for instance?

Answer (score 1):

one way is when you insert a row ,sql give you id of latest inserted row and that you can store into the preference for later use and update it every time after insertion operation.

other way will be the traversing i.e max function or retrieve and use movetoLast with cursor like

```
Cursor cursor = theDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns,null, null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToLast();
```

Comment: The way you comment above is also I thought. Thanks